# hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, rss

I am getting the following error:

' ', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character

Here is my function. I get this error when it hits "reader.MoveToContent()" for the first time. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
Public Function GetSyndicationFeedData(ByVal urlFeedLocation As String) As SyndicationFeed

    Dim settings As New XmlReaderSettings() With { _
      .IgnoreWhitespace = True, _
      .CheckCharacters = True, _
      .CloseInput = True, _
      .IgnoreComments = True, _
      .IgnoreProcessingInstructions = True _
    }

    If [String].IsNullOrEmpty(urlFeedLocation) Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Using reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(urlFeedLocation, settings)
        If reader.ReadState = ReadState.Initial Then
            reader.MoveToContent()
        End If

        ' Now try reading...
        Dim atom As New Atom10FeedFormatter()
        Dim rss20 As New Rss20FeedFormatter()

        ' Atom
        If atom.CanRead(reader) Then
            atom.ReadFrom(reader)
            Return atom.Feed
            'Rss 2.0
        ElseIf rss20.CanRead(reader) Then
            rss20.ReadFrom(reader)
            Return rss20.Feed
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Have you checked the feed to make sure it is a valid XML document?

Comment: I did check the feed on http://validator.w3.org and it is valid. To my understanding 0x1f is a Windows control character. Some people have suggested using Replace((char)(0x1F), ' ') but I am not sure how I would implement that here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code (sorry but it is in c#) to download the feed and replace the offending character.

```
var client = new WebClient();
var feedAsString = client.DownloadString(urlFeedLocation).Replace((char)(0x1F), Convert.ToChar(""));
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(feedAsString)), settings))
{
    // remainder of your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i use this code get error `Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 1, position 2.`