# InvalidOperationException: Hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character (Deserializer function has worked before)

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

*First, if you want to mark this as duplicate, note that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182729/hexadecimal-value-0x1f-is-an-invalid-character) is not working for me. Thanks!*

I am receiving this `InvalidOperationException` on my XML that says

> hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character.

This is the `DeserializeXml` function I am using and it has worked pretty well so far until today that I am apparently receiving some suspicious characters in my XML. The parameter `input` contains the XML code that I am receiving.

```
public object DeserializeXml(string input, Type type, string xmlAttributeRootName = "")
{
    XmlSerializer serializer;
    if (!xmlAttributeRootName.Equals(string.Empty))
        serializer = new XmlSerializer(type, new XmlRootAttribute(xmlAttributeRootName));
    else
        serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
    object result;
    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(input))
    {
        result = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Well, if your XML contains the character U+001F, it's simply not valid XML. Unfortunately the XML serializer will produce such XML if your original source data contains a string with such a character. I'm not sure what an answer to this question would look like...

Comment: @JonSkeet is it possible to remove my `input` string from this character or similar bad characters?

Comment: Well yes, you could - but you'd be potentially losing information. You could use a regex, or for just a single character use `input = input.Replace("\u001f", "")`. But you should really work out how you ended up with this data to start with.

Comment: @JonSkeet The Xml is actually coming from a REST API and I haven't generated that.

Comment: That doesn't really tell us much about where the original actual information comes from, or whether the U+001F is significant data that needs to be preserved somehow.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't think this is the data that my program needs. So I can definitely live without it. It's just that such characters are blocking an enormous amount of analytical data into my database.

Comment: Again, I would really suggest digging into the detail of why you're getting that data to start with. If it's a bug that can be fixed at the source of the data, that would be a lot better than working around already-broken data.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am afraid I am receiving the same error even though I have added your line `input = input.Replace("\u001f", "").` to the function. I have also spoken to the API owner for further information.

Comment: See if your input contains `&#x001f` or anything like that. (Just look for `&#` to start with...)

Comment: You may be having an encoding error and need to read the data properly.  Where is the data coming from?   How are you opening/getting the data?  Is the 1F in the middle of the file or end or the file?

Comment: @JonSkeet same error even with `&#x001f`.

Comment: @jdweng but can be that the function works "sometimes" even if the encoding is wrong? The text comes in Swedish text, by the way but it has always been like that and this very function is working for so many other API methods without a problem.

Comment: Well if you're getting that error, then the XML document clearly contains a U+001F characters somewhere, whether encoded or not. We don't have the document, so can't tell where it is - but *you* could try to reproduce the issue...

Comment: @JonSkeet Now that I tried to remove all `&#`, I am able to deserialize them. Great! Thanks. You could post it as the answer. By the way, I am a big fan of Indepth C#, but it makes me feel far behind in the game. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't really be comfortable in posting that as an answer, as it's not generally something I'd recommend doing.